# Git deployment to development site

Tags: git, deployment

I'm new to Git and trying to wrap my head around this.  I have an existing Drupal site set up on my live server. I want to be able to use git with this, have a separate Git repository, and be able to copy to my local computer the project to work there. This is the the process, I'm assuming, but still a little confused:

1. SSH to the live website (eg. /public_html/drupal-site. Set up a git repository doing a git init in the working folder.
2. Add the files using add . and then commit.
3. Set up a bare repository at another place on the server (eg. /public_html/git). Run git init --bare
4. Clone the live website Git repository to my local machine.
5. Set up a post-receive hook on the Git repository at /public_html/git/.git
6. Then git remote add origin  /public_html/git/.git

When I then make changes on my local machine that I want to go to reflect on the live server, I then do git push origin master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic idea, yes. Ideally you don't want your full Git repository to be in the same directory that your production/development website lives.

A normal deployment flow should look like this:

1. Make changes on local development machine
2. Add and commit changes - `git add . && git commit`
3. Push changes to remote repository set up on the server (this is **not** your website directory) - `git push production master` (where `production` is the name your configured remote)
4. Post-receive hook runs, copies all files required to correct directory and performs any additional build/configuration tasks

If you're comfortable writing your own deployment script for a post-receive hook then it's certainly an option, but you'd really be better off using a tool already designed for this purpose, such as [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) or similar.

Comment: Thanks @rmorrin  Just to clarify though, if the project is already live and I don't have a local copy yet (taking website over from another company), then I would set up a git repository initially on the live site, then clone it to my local environment?

Comment: That's definitely an option yes, but may be unnecessary. If your only wish is to get the files on your dev machine initially then you could just pull down the files with ssh/ftp, create the repository locally, then create a separate repository on the remote server to push your changes to & configure post-deployment hooks. [Here](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/03/automated-deployment-of-wordpress-using-git/) is a nice walk-through of the full process.